# Better way to do Matrix Multiplication using fork and join

Tags: java, multithreading, join, fork, matrix-multiplication

I have this assignment to employ what I have learnt about fork and join. I have heard some rumours that it is possible to achieve a 60x optimisation for `n = 11` to this problem. I can only think of the problem as splitting the multiplication into 4 smaller matrices based on the recursive algorithm provided in `Matrix`, hence I just copied the algorithm and translated them into constructors of `MatrixMultiplication` as seen in the `compute` method. However, I have only managed to achieve a 20x optimisation for the `n = 11` . I do not know if my failure to achieve the required optimisation has to do with the algorithm I'm using or the placement of fork and join. I don't seek an improvement when I changed some of the called constructors into `compute` instead of `fork` and `join`. Can someone give me a hint about how I can even achieve a 60 time improvement optimisation.

Here's the problem description, my attempt and what I meant by a 20x increase(as per output from the program).

[image]

[image]

**MatrixMultiplication**

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

class MatrixMultiplication extends RecursiveTask<Matrix> {

  /** The fork threshold. */
  private static final int FORK_THRESHOLD = 128;

  /** The first matrix to multiply with. */
  private Matrix m1;

  /** The second matrix to multiply with. */
  private Matrix m2;

  /** The starting row of m1. */
  private int m1Row;

  /** The starting col of m1. */
  private int m1Col;

  /** The starting row of m2. */
  private int m2Row;

  /** The starting col of m2. */
  private int m2Col;

  /**
   * The dimension of the input (sub)-matrices and the size of the output
   * matrix.
   */
  private int dimension;

  /**
   * A constructor for the Matrix Multiplication class.
   * @param  m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m1Row The starting row of m1.
   * @param  m1Col The starting col of m1.
   * @param  m2Row The starting row of m2.
   * @param  m2Col The starting col of m2.
   * @param  dimension The dimension of the input (sub)-matrices and the size
   *     of the output matrix.
   */
  MatrixMultiplication(Matrix m1, Matrix m2, int m1Row, int m1Col, int m2Row,
                       int m2Col, int dimension) {
    this.m1 = m1;
    this.m2 = m2;
    this.m1Row = m1Row;
    this.m1Col = m1Col;
    this.m2Row = m2Row;
    this.m2Col = m2Col;
    this.dimension = dimension;
  }


  @Override
  public Matrix compute() {
   /* if (dimension == 1) {
      //Matrix result = new Matrix(1);
      return Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(m1,m2,m1Row,m1Col,m2Row,m2Col,dimension);
      //trivial and return the same type...

      //count the usually we do one and must be pre-existing
    }*/

    if (dimension < FORK_THRESHOLD) {
      return Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col, m2Row, m2Col, dimension);
    }


    int size = dimension / 2;
    Matrix result = new Matrix(dimension); 

    MatrixMultiplication mma11b11 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1,m2,m1Row,m1Col,
      m2Row,m2Col, size);


    MatrixMultiplication mma12b21 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row, 
      m1Col + size, m2Row + size, m2Col, size);


    MatrixMultiplication mma11b12 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col, 
      m2Row, m2Col + size, size);

    MatrixMultiplication mma12b22 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row, 
      m1Col + size, m2Row + size, m2Col + size, size);

    MatrixMultiplication mma21b11 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row + size, 
      m1Col, m2Row, m2Col, size);

    MatrixMultiplication mma22b21 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row + size, 
      m1Col + size, m2Row + size, m2Col, size);


    MatrixMultiplication mma21b12 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row + size, 
      m1Col, m2Row, m2Col + size, size);

    MatrixMultiplication mma22b22 = new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, m1Row + size, 
      m1Col + size, m2Row + size, m2Col + size, size);



    mma11b11.fork();
    mma12b21.fork();
    mma11b12.fork();
    mma12b22.fork();
    mma21b11.fork();
    mma22b21.fork();
    mma21b12.fork();
    mma22b22.fork();

    Matrix a22b22 = mma22b22.join();
    Matrix a21b12 = mma21b12.join();
    Matrix a22b21 = mma22b21.join();
    Matrix a21b11 = mma21b11.join();
    Matrix a12b22 = mma12b22.join();
    Matrix a11b12 = mma11b12.join();
    Matrix a12b21 = mma12b21.join();
    Matrix a11b11 = mma11b11.join();


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a21b12.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a22b22.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i + size];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j + size] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a21b11.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a22b21.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i + size];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a11b12.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a12b22.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j + size] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a11b11.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a12b21.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }


    return result; 
  }
}
```

**Matrix**

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.lang.Runtime;

/**
 * Encapsulate a square matrix of double values.
 */
class Matrix {
  /**
   * 2D square array of double values, storing the matrix.
   */
  double[][] m;
  /**
   * The number of columns and rows in the matrix.
   */
  int dimension;

  private static final int THRESHOLD = 2;

  /**
   * Checks if two matrices are equals.
   * @param   m1  First matrices to check
   * @param   m2  Second matrices to check against
   * @return  true if every elements in m1 and m2 are the same; false otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean equals(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    if (m1.dimension != m2.dimension) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.dimension; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m1.dimension; j++) {
        if (Math.abs(m1.m[i][j] - m2.m[i][j]) > 0.000001) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * A constructor for the matrix.
   * @param  dimension The number of rows.
   */
  Matrix(int dimension) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.m = new double[dimension][dimension];
  }

  /**
   * Generate a matrix of d x d according to the given supplier.
   * @param  dimension The dimension of the matrix
   * @param  supplier The lambda to generate the matrix with.
   * @return The new matrix.
   */
  static Matrix generate(int dimension, Supplier<Double> supplier) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(dimension);
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        matrix.m[row][col] = supplier.get();
      }
    }
    return matrix;
  }

  /**
   * Return a string representation of the matrix, pretty-printed
   * with each row on a single line.
   * @return The string representation of this matrix.
   */
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        s.append(String.format("%.4f", m[row][col]) + " ");
      }
      s.append("\n");
    }
    return s.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Multiply matrix m with this matrix, return a new result matrix.
   * @param  m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m1Row The starting row of m1.
   * @param  m1Col The starting col of m1.
   * @param  m2Row The starting row of m2.
   * @param  m2Col The starting col of m2.
   * @param  dimension The dimension of the input (sub)-matrices and the size
   *     of the output matrix.
   * @return The new matrix.
   */
  public static Matrix nonRecursiveMultiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2,
      int m1Row, int m1Col, int m2Row, int m2Col, int dimension) {
    Matrix result = new Matrix(dimension);
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        double sum = 0;
        // multiply row to col
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
          sum += m1.m[row + m1Row][i + m1Col] * m2.m[i + m2Row][col + m2Col];
        }
        result.m[row][col] = sum;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Multiple two matrices non-recursively.
   * @param m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @return The resulting matrix m1 * m2
   */
  public static Matrix nonRecursiveMultiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    return Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(m1, m2, 0, 0, 0, 0, m1.dimension);
  }

  /**
   * Multiply matrix m with this matrix, return a new result matrix.
   * @param  m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param  m1Row The starting row of m1.
   * @param  m1Col The starting col of m1.
   * @param  m2Row The starting row of m2.
   * @param  m2Col The starting col of m2.
   * @param  dimension The dimension of the input (sub)-matrices and the size
   *     of the output matrix.
   * @return The resulting matrix m1 * m2
   */
  public static Matrix recursiveMultiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2,
      int m1Row, int m1Col, int m2Row, int m2Col, int dimension) {

    // If the matrix is small enough, just multiple non-recursively.
    if (dimension <= THRESHOLD) {
      return Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col, m2Row, m2Col, dimension);
    }

    // Else, cut the matrix into four blocks of equal size, recursively
    // multiply then sum the multiplication result.
    int size = dimension / 2;
    Matrix result = new Matrix(dimension);
    Matrix a11b11 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col, m2Row,
        m2Col, size);
    Matrix a12b21 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col + size,
        m2Row + size, m2Col, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a11b11.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a12b21.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }

    Matrix a11b12 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col, m2Row,
        m2Col + size, size);
    Matrix a12b22 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row, m1Col + size,
        m2Row + size, m2Col + size, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a11b12.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a12b22.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j + size] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }

    Matrix a21b11 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row + size, m1Col,
        m2Row, m2Col, size);
    Matrix a22b21 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row + size, m1Col + size,
        m2Row + size, m2Col, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a21b11.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a22b21.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i + size];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }

    Matrix a21b12 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row + size, m1Col,
        m2Row, m2Col + size, size);
    Matrix a22b22 = recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, m1Row + size, m1Col + size,
        m2Row + size, m2Col + size, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      double[] m1m = a21b12.m[i];
      double[] m2m = a22b22.m[i];
      double[] r1m = result.m[i + size];
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        r1m[j + size] = m1m[j] + m2m[j];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Multiple two matrices recursively but sequentially with
   * divide-and-conquer algorithm.
   * @param m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @return The resulting matrix m1 * m2
   */
  public static Matrix recursiveMultiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    return Matrix.recursiveMultiply(m1, m2, 0, 0, 0, 0, m1.dimension);
  }


  /**
   * Multiple two matrices recursively and parallely with
   * divide-and-conquer algorithm.
   * @param m1 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @param m2 The matrix to multiply with.
   * @return The resulting matrix m1 * m2
   */
  public static Matrix parallelMultiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
    return new MatrixMultiplication(m1, m2, 0, 0, 0, 0, m1.dimension)
        .compute();
  }
}



import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.Duration;
```

**Main**

```
/**
 * Main is the main driver class for testing matrix multiplication.
 * Usage: java Main n
 * 2^n is the dimension of the square matrixOne
 */
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt();

    Random random = new Random(1); 
    int dimension = 1 << n; 



    System.out.println("dimension " + dimension);


    Matrix matrixOne = Matrix.generate(dimension, () -> random.nextDouble());


    Matrix matrixTwo = Matrix.generate(dimension, () -> random.nextDouble());








    Matrix result1 = Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(matrixOne, matrixTwo);


    Matrix result2 = Matrix.parallelMultiply(matrixOne, matrixTwo);


    boolean match = Matrix.equals(result1, result2);
    if (!match) {
      System.out.println("ERROR: matrix multiplication gives inconsistent " +
          "result in sequential and parallel implementations.");
      return;
    }

    double d1 = measureTimeToRun(() -> Matrix.nonRecursiveMultiply(matrixOne, matrixTwo));
    double d2 = measureTimeToRun(() -> Matrix.parallelMultiply(matrixOne, matrixTwo));

    System.out.printf("Parallel %.3f ms Sequential %.3f ms Speedup %.3f times\n", d2, d1, d1 / d2);
  }

  /**
   * Return the average time needed to run the task over three runs.
   * @param  task A lambda expression for the task to be run
   * @return The average time taken in ms.
   */
  private static double measureTimeToRun(Supplier<Matrix> task) {
    final int numOfTimes = 3;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTimes; i++) {
      Instant start = Instant.now();
      Matrix m = task.get();
      Instant stop = Instant.now();
      sum += Duration.between(start, stop).toMillis();
    }
    return sum / numOfTimes;
  }
}
```

Edit: Added in the output of `n = 11` from the program's output in case it causes some confusion.

Comment: to get 60x acceleration, you need more than 60 processor cores in single machine. Do you have 60 cores?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I don't have it sadly, so I take it that you think 60x is impossible too? Do you think that this code might be able to achieve higher than the current 20x at least?

Comment: I guess you have not 20 cores either. So the number 20 you've got is wrong.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I meant if I just compiled and run this program(3 class files), the program will say how much time I have speeded up from the sequential and parallelised version. I could get 20, give me a moment.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I have updated the post. I'm trying to ask if 60+ is achievable with `n = 11`.

Comment: parallel numerical computations have many pitfalls, one of them is processor cache. Maybe the speedup 20x is not because of parallelism, but because in parallel version matrices are small and fit into higher level cache. Maybe if we make sequential computation with the same algorithm though on a single processor core, it would be faster. That is, 20x means not only accelereation because of parallelism, but also deceleration of parallel version because of inefficient usage of cache memory.
In short, 60x acceleration is achievable if you make sequential variant even less effective.